# Querying AD group membership through powershell results in error: Get-ADGroupMember : One or more properties are invalid

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a groups membership to verify the existence of a user so that I can remove the user from the group. I am trying to use the Get-ADGroupMember command, but it only works with certain accounts. unfortunately one of the accounts it does not work with is our service account. Ruining the command results in the error below.

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup
```

results in:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : One or more properties are invalid.  
Parameter name: index  
At line:1 char:12  
+ $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity MyGroup  
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MyGroup:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ArgumentException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here or why this is occurring only on some accounts. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I mean the ovioous question is "Do you actually have a group named MyGroup?"

Comment: yes I do, and I can access the group membership in the same way from a different account.

Comment: So then it sounds like those accounts have different rights in AD.

Comment: But these users can successfully edit the group membership. wouldn't that entitle them to being able to view it?

Comment: How are they editing the group membership?

Comment: using Remove-ADGroupMember or Add-ADGroupMember

Comment: It looks like there is a sharepoint component to the error. Is this related to Sharepoint in any way?

Comment: no it is not. sorry, that was the name of the group before I posted. I edited for clarity

Comment: `Parameter name: index` is odd. That is obviously not an parameter for this. However there are a bunch of ways you could have added that by accident. Do you get the same error if you start PowerShell with the `-NoProfile` switch?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-ADGroupMember` [outputs a list of type `ADPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps#outputs), which means it is looking up each member too. So it's possible that it's choking on one of the members.

See if you get different results with this:

```
(Get-ADGroup MyGroup -Properties member).member
```

That will just spit out the raw `member` attribute of the group, which contains the distinguished name of each member (a list of strings), without actually trying to look up each member.

If that works, then there are other ways to find the info you need (like loop through those members and ignore members that you can't access).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the account you are running under likely does not have read access to that group.  In my organization we purposely remove add a deny right to all other users for the "Domain Admins" group so that people can't query what users have admin access.  When I run your code on my system I get the exact same error.  When I run it as an administrator it works because the administrator account has rights to read that group membership.